# How to allow copying of text within Chart.js tooltips?

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, chart.js, tooltip

I am using Chart.js and would like to know how I can allow a user to hover over a tooltip and select the text inside to copy. Is there a way to do this?

Currently, the tooltip only appears when the user is actively hovered over a specific data point, so I would like the tooltip to stay open until a different data point is hovered over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since chart.js is a canvas renderer you wont be able to copy the text from it since its not a dom element, its drawn on the canvas so if you try to copy it, it will copy the entire canvas as a png image